# Choose first non-null cell from two columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

From a table like this one:

```
id   name      alias
0    John      Null
1    Null      Paul
2    Null      George
3    Ringo     Null
4    Pete      Pete
```

How can I select the first non-Null value between `name` and `alias` columns, and put it into its own `results` field, so that the output would be:

```
id   result
0    John
1    Paul
2    George
3    Ringo
4    Pete
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are basically describing the `COALESCE` function:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-conditional.html

In your case:

```
SELECT id, COALESCE(name, alias) AS result FROM yourtable;
```