# SQL | Select only first filled column

Tags: mysql

I have the following table structure:

```
ID | TXT1 | TXT2 | TXT3 | TXT4 |
```

I just want to show/get the first filled column from this row. Is there any simple way to do this in sql?

At the moment I have a simple Java IF statement to check this.
Examples:

```
ID | TXT1 | TXT2 | TXT3 | TXT4 |
1  | XX1  | XX2  | XX3  |      |
2  |      | YY2  |      | YY4  |
```

If ID == 1 then I just want the value of TXT1.
If ID == 2 then I just want the value of TXT2 etc.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Add some more sample table data and the expected result.

Comment: Just use [COALESCE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choose first non-null cell from two columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42438703/choose-first-non-null-cell-from-two-columns-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE()`:

```
select t.*, COALESCE(TXT1, TXT2, TXT3, TXT4) as first_nonnull
```

This assumes that the "empty" values are `NULL`.  `COALESCE()` is so convenient, that if the strings are empty `''` rather than `NULL`, you can do:

```
select t.*,
       COALESCE(NULLIF(TXT1, ''), NULLIF(TXT2, ''), NULLIF(TXT3, ''), NULLIF(TXT4, '')) as first_nonempty
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this answer:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TXT1!='' THEN TXT1 
            WHEN TXT2!='' THEN TXT2 
            WHEN TXT3!='' THEN TXT3 
            WHEN TXT4!='' THEN TXT4 END
FROM Your_Table
WHERE ID=1
```